# Getting random 'InputObject' validation error in script

Tags: powershell, scripting, remote-server

when executing my script I am getting an Error that I do not quite understand. It tells me that there is a validation error.

I have tested out some different variations but it keeps coming down to the same error.

```
ForEach ($Index in $SQLServer)
{
    $ServiceStatus = Invoke-Command {Get-Service 'MSSQLSERVER'} -comp $Index
    while ($FilteredService.Status -ne 'Running')
    {
        Invoke-Command {Start-Service $ServiceStatus} -comp $Index
        Write-Host $ServiceStatus.Status
        Write-Host "SQL Service starting on " $Index
        function Check-Status 
        {
            Start-Sleep -seconds 30
            $ServiceStatus.Refresh()
            if ($ServiceStatus.Status -eq 'Running')
            {
                Write-Host "SQL Service running"
            }
            else
            {
                Check-Status
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is like this:

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'InputObject'.The argument is null or empty. Provide an arguemnt that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
+ CategoryInfo  : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Service], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationError...
```

Normally this error occurs once some parameter has not been initialized yet , but I just cant figure out which one that is. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
ForEach ($Index in $SQLServer)
{
    $ArrayService = Invoke-Command {Get-Service -Name 'MSSQLSERVER'} -comp $Index

    if ($ArrayService.Status -ne 'Running')
    {
        Invoke-Command {Start-Service $script:ArrayService} -comp $Index
        Write-Host $ArrayService.Status
        Write-Host "SQL Service starting on " $Index
        function Check-Status 
        {
            Start-Sleep -seconds 30
            $ArrayService.Refresh()
            if ($ArrayService.Status -eq 'Running')
            {
                Write-Host "SQL Service running"
            }
            else
            {
                Check-Status
            }
            Check-Status
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Variable`$ServiceStatus` is unknown in the scriptblock of the second `Invoke-Command`. Use `$script:ServiceStatus`. Also, you define an inner function `Check-Status` but never seem to call on that ??

Comment: Ah, ty for the suggestion. I now edited the post above, it still gives me the same error for some reason. 
Also the call of the function was left out because I didnt want to go that far yet, but added it in so its clearer.

Comment: You need to check if you indeed get a service object returned in `$ArrayService` from the first line in the loop. Does your variable `$Index` contain a valid computername? Also, always define a function **before** calling it. PowerShell reads from top to bottom and left to right.

Comment: I just wrote `Invoke-Command {Start-Service 'MSSQLSERVER'} -comp $Index` there and it works fine now. It is probably not the most beautiful solution but ye..
Also putting the function call below was also a good idea.